# Meter un "puntero" en una imagen de un mapa en Java desde un Layout

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse

Tengo que crear una aplicación en Java con interfáz grafica,la cual al hacer click en un botón "Crear señal" el cual me permita visualizar en un JPanel la imagen de un mapa cualquiera , y con el mouse poder posicionar varios "Puntadores" o "Puntos" en dicho mapa y salvar informacion relacionada a aquel punto por ejemplo "calle,avenida etc"

Al hacer click en cada "Punto" este me muestre en un JLabel o JText la información salvada de aquel "Punto".

- Como se podria hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiero que veas este artículo que puede ayudarte:

https://dzone.com/articles/google-maps-java-swing [Google Maps in Java Swing Application](https://dzone.com/articles/google-maps-java-swing)

Comment: Gracias lo veo como una posible solución , pero por otra parte talvez complique las cosas mas de lo necesario , de todos modos me resultara útil.